# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils when the code executed on server

Tags: java, gradle, apache-commons

I had code below:

```
if (!ListUtils.intersection(listProducts, listProducts2).isEmpty()){
...
}
```

It works fine on my local. However, when we deployed it on the server and run it, we go the error below

```
ERROR [2019-08-18 23:02:49,593] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: f39815ce59e1cd18
! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils
! at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
! at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
! at javassist.Loader.delegateToParent(Loader.java:426)
! at javassist.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:312)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
! ... 77 common frames omitted
! Causing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils
```

Note that we use gradle to manage the dependencies. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Would it make sense to show at least the relevant part of your gradle file referring to commons.collections :-)

Answer (score 0):

please check /WEB-INF/lib contains commons-collections jar or not, clean & build might help as well.